Completion of $S(\mathfrak{h})$ at a maximal ideal
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Denote by $W$ the Weyl group of root system of $\mathfrak{g}$. Now we consider the symmetric algebra $S(\mathfrak{h})$, which can be identified with the polynomial functions on the dual space $\mathfrak{h}^{\ast}$ of $\mathfrak{h}$. Let $\lambda\in \mathfrak{h}^{\ast}$ be a regular integral weight and $\rho$ the half sum of positive roots. Denote by $I$ the maximal ideal of $S(\mathfrak{h})$ consisting of polynomial functions vanishing at $\lambda+\rho$. Similarly, let $J$ be the maximal ideal of $S(\mathfrak{h})^{W}$ consisting of $W$-invariant polynomial functions vanishing at $\lambda+\rho$.
In lemma 3 of Bernstein's paper "Trace in categories", the author claims that  there is a natrual isomorphism between the completion rings $\widehat{S(\mathfrak{h})^W}_J$ and $\widehat{S(\mathfrak{h})}_I$. So how to understand this "natrual isomorphism" and can I write down this isomorphism explicitly?

There is a typo in your headline
